# Upload file from client to server using file path in client machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an image that is in this directory: D:\images\nature.png
and I hava an html page that is have the image directory as a var in javascript code

```
var imgDir="D:\images\nature.png"
```

so I don't use an `<input type="file"/>` to select the image.
Is there any way to upload this image to server "ASP or PHP" using pure Javascript, Ajax, or Jquery?

Comment: That would be an enormous security hole. You go to a web site, they could run a script that uploads all your files.

Comment: you must `use an <input type="file"/> to select the image`